# finding simple information hidden in the server

Tags: server

I am not a programmer or work in IT.

I am seeking information from a specific organisation--number of times a specific document has been downloaded (by the general public) from its website.

The organisation has claimed that it does not hold this information. However, this statement comes from the public enquiries section not the IT department.

Is it possible that the information is actually recorded on the server (or elsewhere)?

And the server needs to have something like a specific small script to enable extraction of the desired information?

How else might the desired information be found?

I did attempt an answer through other sites. I am not a programmer, and I couldn't understand the technical nature of that information.

Comment: This is not really on-topic for stackoverflow (which is about programming questions). It **might** fit on server fault, but even there it is basically unanswerable without [knowing more about the website](https://sitereport.netcraft.com).